# kendo dropDownList issue where setting index not working to select initial option value

Tags: kendo-ui

Has anyone else ran into this issue? setting index for the kendoDropDownList option is not working

```
$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 2,
    change: onChange
});
```

You can view on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/design48/E57J3/7/. It should select 3rd item for `Gray` for color drop down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in your `kendoDropDownList` but the fact that you set the color multiple times.

You set it in Kendo DropDownList when you say:

```
$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 2,
    change: onChange
});
```

You do it again in:

```
color.select(0);
```

And once again in:

```
<input id="color" value="1" />
```

Try removing all but one and you get the right value.

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/E57J3/8/

Comment: Perfect @OnaBai, that makes sense and works. I missed those from just copy-n-pasting from kendoui samples